# How to add Custome Tag in sentry appender

Tags: .net, sentry

We are using sentry appender to log our errors to sentry, as part of additional data in sentry I want to add a custom tag into sentry data.
here is the sentry appender configuration:

```
     <appender name="SentryAppender" type="SharpRaven.Log4Net.SentryAppender, SharpRaven.Log4Net">
        <DSN value="https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@sentry.io/XXXXXX" />
        <Logger value="SentryLog4Net_IF Windows Service" />
        <Release value="Development" />
        <Environment value="DEV" />
        <threshold value="OFF" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline%exception" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

Our application is a C# MVC application with .net framework 4.8